# SSIS package upgrade 2012 to 2016, event handler, parameters, package explorer tabs gone

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, migration

I am working on the upgrade of SSIS packages from 2012 to 2016. I am using Visual Studio 2017 to do the task, basically I am creating a new project on VS 2017, targeting the project to SQL 2016 (that's the version we have) and then adding the existing SSIS project from the 2012 version.

The issue is that after upgrading the package, I only see the Control Flow and Data Flow tabs available, I am not able to find the event handlers, parameters or package explorer tabs.

Here is how it looks right now

[image]

Here is what I am looking for

[image: Here is what I am looking for.]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: when running `upgrade package wizard`, did u get any error? I followed this: http://www.stefanjohansson.org/2015/02/issues-upgrading-an-ssis-solutionpackage-from-visual-studio-2012-to-vs-2013/

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FiiC.png)I would recommend using VS15.  At my last client I had issues with VS17 deleting script task content when upgrading packages from SS08r2 to SS16 and pulling back to VS15 resolved it for me.  *However*, others have had issues with VS15 as well so its kind of a crapshoot right now.  I believe I also went back to SSDT 16.5 to avoid any SS17 "support".

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32896399-script-tasks-losing-code-in-ssdt-17-1-for-visual-s